# SQL sort by, order by case when, item to specific position

Tags: sql, sqlite, case, sql-order-by, union-all

How to put item in a specific position?

I'd like to put item on a 5th position:

```
`id`='randomId243'
```

So far my sorting looks like that:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN `id` = 'randomId123' THEN 0
        WHEN `id` = 'randomId098' THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END, `name` ASC
```

I don't know yet which id will be in position 2,3,4. I'd prefer to avoid run another query/subquery to get ids of items from position 2-4

So final order should be like this:

> - randomId123
> - randomId098
> - just item alphabetical
> - just item alphabetical
> - just item alphabetical
> - randomId243
> - just item alphabetical

Comment: If you just need to sort by the number after the id you can strip out the last character with a substring function and then just order by the substring that just has the number in it.

Comment: Id could be different. I just put like that to show an order.

Comment: This needs sample data, and some sort of logical sort other than "I want to put it here cause I want to." If the latter is your goal and your sort order is truly not derministic, you need another column to track and manage desired row number/placement by itself.

Comment: Your numbering is 0 based, right? Don't you mean *the 6th position*, after positions 0,1,2,3,4?

Comment: I've edited ids to not mislead. I just have a requirement position 0 should be this id, 1 another id, 5th another id. Rest of unknown position just fill alphabetically. Ids can vary, but I know only this few on start.

Comment: forpas could be like this. The problem is that I need to put an item on a specific position. It would be easier to do it in a memory, but sql is faster. The list is big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function for your current ordering to rank the rows initially.
Then create 3 groups of rows: the rows on top, the row with `'item5'` and the rows below `'item5'` which will be assembled with `UNION ALL` and sorted by group and row number:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE id WHEN 'item0' THEN 0 WHEN 'item1' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, name) AS rn
    FROM tablename
)  
SELECT id, name
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, 1 grp FROM cte WHERE id <> 'item5' ORDER BY rn LIMIT 5)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *, 2 FROM cte WHERE id = 'item5'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, 3 FROM cte WHERE id <> 'item5' ORDER BY rn LIMIT -1 OFFSET 5) -- negative limit means there is no limit
)
ORDER BY grp, rn;
```

Note that instead of:

```
ORDER BY CASE id WHEN 'item0' THEN 0 WHEN 'item1' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, name
```

you could use:

```
ORDER BY id = 'item0' DESC, id = 'item1' DESC, name
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/W5EI8Umc).